# generate a specific matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, bsxfun

I have matrix:
   `x=[0 0 0;5 8 0; 7 6 0]`

I want matrix:
   `m=[0 0 0;5 8 0;7 6 0;   0 0 8;5 8 8;7 6 8;   0 0 16;5 8 16;7 6 16]`

I want that the third column of matrix `x` gets multiplied each time by 8 while other two columns remain same. I want this to continue until the value in third column reaches 72.

How can I do it with `bsxfun` or  any other way?

Comment: Multiplied by 8 or added with 8? And which element in column-3 must reach 72, any one element? Does it have to reach at exactly 72, or maybe to have it reach *at least* 72? I think a better sample `x` would be with different elements in column-3, rather than all zeros as you have.

Comment: Third column has to be added by 8 each time the matrix repeats..till it reaches 72. That is to say, for the first repetition i.e forth row, third column will be 8 8 8 . For seventh row i.e second repetition , third column will be 16 16 16 and so on till thid column reaches 72.

Comment: Could u also answer my second question. what if i wanted to add a constant to column 1 and column2 with each matrix repetition. That is to say,if my constant to be added is 5 ,then my first column in second repetition of matrix is 5 10 12 and second column becomes 5 13 11. In third repetition first column becomes 10 15 17 and second column becomes 10 18 16 and so on. During this entire process my third column goes on with addition of 8 each time ( as u have answered)

Comment: Could you also clarify the second part of my earlier query, repeating here again - "And which element in column-3 must reach 72, any one element? Does it have to reach at exactly 72, or maybe to have it reach at least 72?". Consider something other than all zeros in column -3 of the starting matrix and explain to us the expected output after each iteration/repetition?

Comment: all the elements of column 3. They have to reach exactly 72 as I am interested in running it 10 times and with each time an addition of 8 is required . So it reaches 72 . If my first column was all -3 then first repetition will give 5 5 5 in third column  and second repetition would give 13 13 13 till it has repeated 10 times

Comment: Could you edit your question with that *second question*, so that the solutions would stay coherent with the new requirements as well?

Comment: I have x=[1 2 1 1; 4 5 1 1 ; 7 8 1 1].   I want a matrix in which this matrix repeats itself 10 times using repmat function and with each repetition the first and second columns of the basic matrix ,that is x, increase by 5.  Thus my fourth, fifth and sixth row (first repetition) will be [6 7 1 1 ; 9 10 1 1 ; 12 13 1 1] .In second repetition ,that is 7th,8th and 9th row, it would be [11 12 1 1 ; 14 15 1 1 ; 17 18 1 1 ] and so on till 10 repetitions are performed.  In this question last column need not be repeated as multiple. I was confused.Sorry about that.That was entirely different question

Comment: Since the requirements are different for the second part, I would suggest asking a new question with these new requirements. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following two assumptions, you could try an approach listed thereafter -

1. Keep on `adding` rather than `multiplying`.
2. All *final* elements in `column-3` to reach at least `72`.

**Approach #1 [With `bsxfun`]**

```
stopn = 72; %// stop adding till this number
add_factor = 8; %// Add factor to be added at each iteration to get to 72
ntimes = ceil(max((stopn - x(:,3))/add_factor)) %// no. of iterations needed

%// Get the starting 2d version of matrix to be added to x iteratively
x_add_2d = zeros(size(x)); %//
x_add_2d(:,3) = add_factor;

%// Get the complete version of matrix to be added (in 3d), then add to x
x_add_3d = bsxfun(@plus,x,bsxfun(@times,x_add_2d,permute([0:ntimes],[1 3 2])))

%// Concatenate along rows to form a 2D array as the final output
out = reshape(permute(x_add_3d,[1 3 2]),size(x_add_3d,1)*(ntimes+1),[])
```

**Approach #2 [With `repmat`]**

```
stopn = 72; %// stop adding till this number
add_factor = 8; %// Add factor to be added at each iteration to get to 72
ntimes = ceil(max((stopn - x(:,3))/add_factor)); %// no. of iterations needed

out = repmat(x,[ntimes+1 1]) %// replicated version of x
add_col3 = repmat([0:8:ntimes*8],size(x,1),1) %// column-3 values to be added
out(:,3) =  out(:,3) + add_col3(:) %// add those for the final output
```

---

Sample run -

```
x =
    52    43    57
    41    40    48
    41    49    50
out =
    52    43    57
    41    40    48
    41    49    50
    52    43    65
    41    40    56
    41    49    58
    52    43    73
    41    40    64
    41    49    66
    52    43    81
    41    40    72
    41    49    74
```

Comment: @SaurabhTariyal If this answered your original question, consider accepting it by clicking on the hollow checkmark next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you can do it using `repmat` and `kron` :

```
clear
clc

x=[0 0 0;5 8 0; 7 6 0];

%// Generate last column containing the values form 0 to 72, each repeated 3 times.
y = kron(0:8:72,ones(1,3))

%// The first 2 columns remain the same, so we just repeat them 10 times.

out = [repmat(x(:,1:2),10,1) y(:)]
```

Using square brackets to concatenate, the output is this:

```
out =

 0     0     0
 5     8     0
 7     6     0
 0     0     8
 5     8     8
 7     6     8
 0     0    16
 5     8    16
 7     6    16
 0     0    24
 5     8    24
 7     6    24
 0     0    32
 5     8    32
 7     6    32
 0     0    40
 5     8    40
 7     6    40
 0     0    48
 5     8    48
 7     6    48
 0     0    56
 5     8    56
 7     6    56
 0     0    64
 5     8    64
 7     6    64
 0     0    72
 5     8    72
 7     6    72
```